# compare data between two fragments

Tags: android

I have two fragments in my app, one has the List View, each list contains 15 text views which gets the values from SQL database and the other fragment contains toggle buttons where each toggle represent an unique value. I want to change the style/background, of every text view who is equal with the checked toggle button. for example: when i press toggle button number 7, all the values in the other activity who are equal to 7, change their style/background, also reset style/background of the text view if the same button is unchecked. How to do this?

Comment: You should use fragments.

Comment: @SvenB in fact they are fragments

Comment: can you set tag to the value. And then iterate through a list of textviews, if tag = then change color/style

Comment: @androidlover you could use the observer pattern (google).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the example given by google : [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

The "Define an Interface" part is for your fragment that contains toggle button.

The "Deliver a Message to a Fragment" part is for your listFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Use a static array or similar variable to hold all elements which should be of a different style. You can add to the static variable in Activity 2 and in Activity 1 you can check it in the onResume and set the theme accordingly.

Alternatively you can start Activity 2 from Activity 1 with [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and your changes can be hand back from Activity 2 to Activity 1 and checked with onActivityResult.